# Is it possible to have coordinate system with 3D cursor as origin?

Tags: coordinates

I would like to do some precise vertex positionning with regard to the 3D cursor, eg put a vertex at coordinate (0.1,0.1,0.1) from 3D cursor (which I can position very easily to a convenient position). Is that possible? I am not talking about the local coordinate system, which takes the object's origin as origin.

Comment: You could snap it to the 3D cursor, then move it the desired amount.

Comment: That's a way to do it, but what if I want to have the coordinate of the point, just the coordinate?

Comment: The coordinates of the 3D cursor?

Comment: No, the coordinate of the point relative to the 3D cursor. For example, I put the 3D cursor at same spot as a vertex, and I want to have the coordinate of another point relative to that point...

Answer (score 2):

Xavier, you can position a selection at a set of coordinates in the edit menu by using the 3D cursor location on the Properties menu <kbd>N</kbd>.
You can then move a selected point to the cursor location using the Snap menu <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and selecting "Selection to Cursor"
This positions the selection using the global coordinate system.
[image: cursor location]
You can also enter the coordinates of the active vertex directly using that same menu.
[image: vertex position]
Beneath the coordinates, you  specify weather the location is in local or global coordinates.
You could then combine that with the cursor location.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, but it can be quite tiresome to copy/paste the cursor coordinates fir every point, it would be so much simpler to have the coordinates in 3Dcursor coordinate system...

Comment: Another solution that could do what I want (but with too many operations) is to place the 3D cursor, change the origin of the model, and then use the local coordinates. What I would like is to have the same, without having to move the origin.

Comment: Is there another program generating the coordinates?

Comment: No, but my mind is kind of wired to work that way. I use some softwares in my job that use the same kind of system, only in 2D instead of 3D. It can really accelrate thing to make preise move when you do all in relative coordinates...

Comment: Are you trying to enter coordinates for vertices as you create them, like inputing coordinates for a polyline in AutoCAD?

Comment: kind of, what I usually do is make a rough design and then adjust the vertices precisely.